# Directed Graph - SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a directed graph (with backward references) via SQLAlchemy; how can I get the desired output listed below? [*see section titled 'Desired Output'*]

---

## Example code:

### example_db.py

```python
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, Table
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref

Base = declarative_base()

node_connector = Table('node_connector', Base.metadata, 
    Column('from_node_handle', Integer, ForeignKey('node.handle')),
    Column('to_node_handle', Integer, ForeignKey('node.handle')))


class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    handle = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    next_nodes = relationship('Node',
        secondary=node_connector,
        foreign_keys=[node_connector.c.to_node_handle],
        backref=backref("previous_nodes",
            foreign_keys=[node_connector.c.from_node_handle]))
```

### test/example_db_test.py

***Module being executed***

```python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import unittest

from ..example_db import Base, Node

class TestNodeDB(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)    
        SessionMaker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.__session = SessionMaker()
        Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    def test_node_creation(self):
        node_a = Node()
        node_b = Node()
        node_c = Node()
        self.__session.add(node_a)
        self.__session.add(node_b)
        self.__session.add(node_c)
        node_a.next_nodes.append(node_b)
        node_b.next_nodes.append(node_c)
        self.__session.commit()

        nodes = self.__session.query(Node)

        for node in nodes:
            print "Node handle " + str(node.handle) + ":"
            for next_node in node.next_nodes:
                print "\t next node handle " + str(next_node.handle)
            for previous_node in node.previous_nodes:
                print "\t previous node handle " + str(previous_node.handle)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

## Output

### Actual output

```
Node handle 1:
Node handle 2:
     next node handle 2
     previous node handle 2
Node handle 3:
     next node handle 3
     previous node handle 3
```

### Desired Output

```
Node handle 1:
     next node handle 2
Node handle 2:
     next node handle 3
     previous node handle 1
Node handle 3:
     previous node handle 2
```

---

How can I get this desired output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy even has documentation on this: [Self-Referential Many-to-Many Relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship), which covers exactly what you want. Basically, you got it *almost* right, just instead of using the `foreign_keys` setting use `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin`:

```
next_nodes = relationship('Node',
    secondary=node_connector,
    primaryjoin=handle==node_connector.c.to_node_handle,
    secondaryjoin=handle==node_connector.c.from_node_handle,
    backref="previous_nodes",
    )
```

Now your tests work. One additional detail: You don't need to add `node_b` and `node_c`: They are added through the casacde: If `node_a` is in the session and you add something to a configured relationship, they will also be added. Also you don't need to `commit`: When you query the session figures it must first flush, then query.

And also pay attention that you need to watch over loading strategies here. Take the example on [Configuring Self-Referential Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#configuring-self-referential-eager-loading) to figure out a way that works for you.